# Issue to build an sql query - running in sql developer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql and have the a table called Event with the following column:

- ID
- Stage
- Type
- Location
- Country

So a country can be Italy,Brazil,England or All.

Basically I need to build a query that i will pass country as parameter and it will return :

1. All country if All is passed as parameter and return only the
   countries which their stage and type are not the same
2. If any other country other than All is passed as parameter then it should return
   for the choosen country and All country also with their stage and
   type not the same

So for example if All is passed i will recieve data for All countries only which there stage and type are not the same

If Brazil is passed then i will receive for Brazil and All countries which there stage and type are not the same.

So If I have query for country Brazil on the following record:

```
ID: 1
Stage: C
Type: Football
Location:City
Country:All

ID: 2
Stage: C
Type: Football
Location:City
Country:Brazil

ID 3
Stage: D
Type: VolleyBall
Location:City
Country:All

 ID 4
Stage: E
Type: handball
Location:City
Country:Brazil
```

It will return  ID 3 and ID 4 only because for the others the Type and the stage are the same.

If for All countries:

```
ID: 1
Stage: C
Type: basketball
Location:City
Country:All

ID: 2
Stage: D
Type: handball
Location:City
Country:Brazil

ID 3
Stage: C
Type: VolleyBall
Location:City
Country:ALL
```

It should return :
Only ID 1 and 3.

I Know it will be something like this :

```
select *
from Event
where country =
```

Any help will be most welcome thanks in advance

Comment: Are you really using SQL Developer (which is Oracle's SQL GUI client) with **Microsoft SQL Server**?

Answer (score 0):

The country part is easy.

You want to get all rows where either the country is All or the country matches your parameter

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Event
 WHERE Country = @Country or Country = 'All'
```

Your second part is considerably more difficult.

If I understand you want to return all rows where that Stage/Type combo appears only once.  To do this you would need to first go get the count of each of those combos, and then select the ones where that count = 1

```
SELECT Stage, Type, count(*) occurrences
  FROM Events 
  GROUP BY Stage, Type
  HAVING count(*) = 1
```

This query groups them by Stage and Type and counts them and selects only those that have 1 occurrence.

You can combine this with the first query  in a join to get what I think you want.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Event
  JOIN (
      SELECT Stage, Type, count(*) occurrences
        FROM Events 
        GROUP BY Stage, Type
        HAVING count(*) = 1
 ) uniqueEvents ON uniqueEvents.Stage = Event.Stage AND uniqueEvents.Type = Event.Type
 WHERE Country = @Country or Country = 'All'
```